# How to use hosts in my playbook for initiating my template

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook to initiate a conf to servers that requires hostname. I want to pass my hosts that define in playbook as group so as to loop the variables in my jinja2 template. And I don't want to set the hosts in vars(because that was already define in playbook, I don't know the reason for re-define)

For example:
host file:

```
[test_servers]
t1
t2
t3
[test2_servers]
t2
t4
```

playbook:

```
- hosts: test_servers
  tasks:
      - name: generate my conf
        template:
            src: templates/temp.conf.j2
            dest: "test.conf"
            force: True
        vars:
            hosts: test_servers # So far I need to declare the var here duplicately,  I've group my server in host file and I just want to use the current group.
```

temp.conf

```
 ....
 {% for host in groups[hosts] %}
 Entry.{{ loop.index }} = {{ host }}
 {% endfor %}
 ....
```

I wonder if there is a better way to pass the hosts that set in playbook to my jinja2 template so I can re-use the playbook for different hosts. For example, I just need to reset the playbook hosts to test2, no need to rewrite the vars.

Answer (score 1):

There is no [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) with the name of the group, but there is **ansible_play_hosts_all**

> List of all the hosts that were targeted by the play

Remove *vars* and use *ansible_play_hosts_all* in the template

```
- hosts: test_servers
  tasks:
      - name: generate my conf
        template:
            src: templates/temp.conf.j2
            dest: "test.conf"
            force: True

{% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
Entry.{{ loop.index }} = {{ host }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know there is a ansible internal variable for that. BTW, Maybe I'm using the newer version, it should be {% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all %} and you don't need to put "{{ }}" to use the variable.

Comment: You're right. It's an error to expand a variable inside a Jinja [control structure](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-control-structures). I've fixed the answer. Thank you.